# Formato de fechas Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException:

Tags: java

```
String date_s = "2019-10-29T00:00:00.0-0600";


    SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = dt.parse(date_s);

    SimpleDateFormat dt1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    System.out.println(dt1.format(date));
```

//Quiero dar de salida el siguiente formnato 2019-10-29

Pero me sale un error de las siguiente manera, entiendo que es el formato en el que se lo estoy dando, pero que formato se le debe de dar para convertir esa cadena de fecha a formato de salida yyyy-MM-dd.

> Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2019-10-29T00:00:00.0"
>       at java.base/java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:395)
>       at Main.main(Main.java:19)

Answer (score 0):

No se si su objetivo se pasar por los tipos de datos de fecha (Date), pero esto ayudaria

```
String date_s = "2019-10-29T00:00:00.0-0600";
String fechaFormato = date_s.subString(0, date_s.indexOf("T"));
System.out.println(fechaFormato); //2019-10-29
```

Comment: El objetivo es usar las fechas de la clase Calendar, sin embargo ayuda en el resultado, gracias.
Saludos.